# Array of Numbers and Half Numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to populate an array with sizes that are measured in whole and half numbers (i.e. 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12). So far I have:

```
(10..12).map{ |size| [size, size + 0.5] }.flatten[0...-1]
```

Does a more eloquent way of doing this exist in Ruby without having to flatten and remove the last element?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My personal favorite:

```
>> (10..12).step(0.5).to_a
=> [10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5, 12.0]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Very clean and easy to follow! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. It's features like this why I <3 ruby Enumerables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambdas (notice that it outputs floats) - I'll let you decide if that is more eloquent.

```
irb(main):001:0> fn = ->(x, y) { (x*2..y*2).map { |i| i / 2.0 } }
=> #<Proc:0x007fa782b0a4b0@(irb):1 (lambda)>
irb(main):002:0> fn.call(10, 12)
=> [10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5, 12.0]
```

Comment: Same comment as the one I left for Willie.

Comment: I made it clear on my answer that it outputted floats only.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed you want the values in the returned array to alternate between `Fixnum` and `Float`, as in your example:

```
(10..12).flat_map { |size| [size, size + 0.5] }.tap { |a| a.pop }
   #=> [10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12]
```